# ReactJS Reusable component styling

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have reusable component. This component has 2 buttons. on one page both of buttons are being displayed but on the second page I want to display only one,

Any suggestions please? I tried to pass style as a props but it did not work

I mean this :

```
    const MoneyManagementOffers = ({text,title,style}) => { 
   return <Button style={style} border="none" margin="58.75px auto;" primary width="134px;">
            Learn More
          </Button>
```

This just a part from my code.This is the button I want to hide on the second page.

This is how I tried to use that style prop when I called this component in another place :

```
      <MoneyManagementOffers style={display:"none;"} text={"Get Started"}/>
```

This did not work. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

I'm using styled-components

Comment: You should do it in parent component. The component itself must not know whether it should be displayed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You don't render the button at all by introducing a new prop called `shouldShow` which would default to `true` for example:

```
const MoneyManagementOffers = ({text,title,style, shouldShow = true}) => { 
return shouldShow && <Button style={style} border="none" margin="58.75px auto;" primary width="134px;">
        Learn More
      </Button>;
```

And when you want to hide it:

`<MoneyManagementOffers shouldShow={false}/>`

and when you want to show it:

`<MoneyManagementOffers style={....} text={"Get Started"}/>`

You can check out the official documentation regarding [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

**Solution 2:**

Decide at the parent level whether you want to render `MoneyManagementOffers` at all or not by using [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) (the same syntax as solution 1)

**Solution 3:**

If you really want to pass `display: none` which I don't suggest, you should wrap the prop in an outer `{}` like `style={{ display: "none" }}` as it should be an `object`, not `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set hidden props in component because component should be as dumb as possible.
It's better to decide on parent level:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    ...someCode;
    const renderOffers = () => {
      if (someCondition) {
        return null
      }
      return <MoneyManagementOffers ... />
   }
   return (
     <>
        ...someCode
        {renderOffers()}
     </>
   )
}
```